# Node js ejs session not closing/opening correctly

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, browser-cache

I have a simple app that uses node for the backend. Whenever a user signs in, I use a cookie to store the session, and when they sign out, I delete that cookie, also, I use ejs to display certain data to the user (like their user name).

The problem is that, for whatever reason, when I enter a view without being signed in (example, the index page), after signing in, that view is presented as if I wasn´t sign in (example, the user name is not present), but other views are present as if I was (the cookie is there in both cases); also, after signing out, the views that I rendered while being signing in, are still presented as if I was, while the other are not (and in this case, the cookie is not present).

I may assume that is something to do with how node/ejs/browsers render things, that there may store something in a cache, and they don´t even bother to ask for it again (after signing in/out), but this breaks all the front´s login, since it assumes that the user is singed in/out when it is not.

What can I do to force to reload the view, and thus, check if what I explained this what is happening?

Edit: my logout code is as follows:

backend:

```
router.get('/logOut',verifiyLogin, async (req, res) =>{
    res.clearCookie('cookie');
    return res.status(200).send();
});
```

frontend;

```
  $.ajax({
            url: url+"/logOut",
            type: "get",
            success: function(response) {
                window.location.assign('/');
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert('Error: '+xhr.response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe this is browser side page caching. Look for 302 status codes in  the Network tab of your browser devtools.

Comment: @O.Jones nope, I checked and nothing returned a 302. All are 200.

Comment: @O.Jones Looks like that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your signin and signout code.
I am sharing you my approach might help you.
I am using express-session and cookie-parser.
On signout I am destroying the session and deleting the cookie from response.

```
req.session.destroy(function(err) {
   res.clearCookie('yourCookieName');
   res.redirect('/yourDestinationRoute'); 
});
```

Comment: Already added. As you can see is pretty much the same.